# What is the optimal way to animate a drawable within a view using the animator classes?

Tags: android, animation, drawing, hardware-acceleration

I have read about [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) and [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#layers-anims) but I am still uncertain what is the most efficient way to use the animator classes. (For the sake of this question I don't need to support devices before Honeycomb. So I want to use the animator classes.)

For example, say I have a View. In this view I have a BitmapDrawable that I want to fade in. There are also many other elements within the view that won't change.

What property or object would be best to use with the animator? The drawable? A paint that I am drawing the bitmap with in onDraw? Something else?

How can this be done to be most efficient with hardware acceleration? Will this require calling invalidate for each step of the animation or is there a way to animate just the drawable and not cause the rest of the view to be redrawn completely for each step of the animation?

I guess I imagine an optimal case would be the rest of the view not having to be completely redrawn in software, but rather hardware acceleration efficiently fading the drawable.

Any suggestions or pointers to recommended approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I think you are asking this because it is causing trouble. The animation is probably invalidating everything but we might find a workaround if you show us the view hierarchy you have. Please specify what you are animating in it.

Comment: Nope, haven't written anything yet, just trying to get all the information before I do. :)

Comment: Well, if the animation works well on average devices, then we are okay to go. However, if it is noticeably heavy, even after the usual enhancements such as hardware acceleration (which might not always be available), one should find his own solution. For example, if you are animating a background that is causing your whole hierarchy to be invalidated, you create an snapshot of the hierarchy and animate the background behind it. Anyway, it is essentially your decision whether to put effort since it will probably work out with hardware acceleration and on most devices. (hopefully :)

Answer (score 4):

With the use of the Object Property Animators, basically they're just math functions that repeatedly call a "setN()" method every X miliseconds where "N" is the property you want to change.

In the example provided in the case of alpha, both would require a call to `invalidate()` to redraw the View that you are animating.  The difference being when you call `setAlpha()` on the `View` object, it calls `invalidate()` for you.  If you were to set the target Object to the `Paint` object that is used to draw the drawable, you would still need to call `invalidate()` on the `View` so it will redraw with the new `Paint` parameters.

Ideally you want to set the target to the highest level child you can so the redrawing only happens on the views you want to animate.  If you set the target to the root View, for example, it will call `invalidate()` on every child in the entire ViewGroup which will in turn call `draw()` on every child in the ViewGroup.  If you set it to a top level `ImageView`, then only `ImageView` will be redrawn.

To best utilize the Hardware, you need to use the Layer properties.  First, you need to decide what the top-most parent View you want to animate will be.  If you want to only fade the `Drawable`, then it will be the `Drawable` or containing `View`.  If you want to fade everything, then it will be the root view.  Whatever you decide to animate will be applied to the `View` as a whole at once.

Use `setLayerType()` on the parent view just before you start the Animator.  Set it to `View#LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE`.  Then set an `AnimationListener` and reset the LayerType to `View#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE` or `View#LAYER_TYPE_NONE` upon completion of the animator.

```
myParentView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
myObjectAnimator.addListener(new ViewAnimator.AnimatorListener() {
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    myParentView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE);
  }
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
  }
  public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
  }
  public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
    myParentView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
  }
}
myObjectAnimator.start();
```

In this case, if you were to translate `myParentView` by using the `translateX` property, then it will put layer `myParentView` and all it's children into one plane.  Put it in to hardware memory. Translate the entire view all at once.  Then, upon completion, remove `myParentView` from memory.

**EDIT:**

One final note, Alpha wreaks havoc on the CPU.  If you have something on half-alpha and translate it across the View, it will be harder to render than if you simply translate the View.  Use it sparingly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can overlay a new view(which contains the animator only) on your original one. the new view set to Transparent.

the reset you should do is invalid the new view without your original view.

Answer (score 1):

After going through your queries I will suggest please go through this [standard document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) which is neat to make you understand how to use `invalidate()` properly. Secondly, there are different ways already provided by android API to work with animation in different situations.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html), I hope most of your doubts will be cleared. Please go through the sub-sections and related blog mentioned their.

Hope this will help you.